# Unable to find element in browser opened by clicking link in App

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

I am trying to automate a hybrid app using appium for android and ios. I am able to click on the contact us link present in the app.On clicking it, chrome browser is opened and contact us page is displayed. There i am able to get the WEBVIEW of the browser and able to switch to the browser, but i am unable to find any elements in contact us page. I tried getting the pagesource of the page also, but it is showing the pagesource of my app only(As my app is hybrid).

Please help me on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're using the `AndroidDriver` or the `AppiumDriver` of the generic type `<MobileElement>` Try using `<WebElement>` for locating the elements on browser instead :)